# Merge pen tool paths to be able to select each segment individually

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have drawn an image using the pen tool. They are currently individual paths, I want to merge these paths to create a single vector shape so that I can be able to select each segment individually using the white arrow tool and add a different colour to each segment.

[image: Screenshot]

Have tried selecting all then Object > Expand. Then Pathfinder > Merge (wont let me merge)

It only works if I add 1pt stroke. Then Object > Expand > Fill & Stroke > Ok ....then I am able to merge but this means having visible stroke paths I cant remove.

Comment: It's not so clear what are you asking: why do you want to merge the paths if after you want to color every stroke individually? Are you talking about the strokes or getting the inside shapes to fill?

Comment: @daniello I do not want to use any stroke. The paths will be invisible, just want to color the segments created by the paths

Comment: Is this some translation thing a segment is a piece of a path. and a segment thus could not be anything other than sttroked. So you want to fill the area between paths? If so use shapebuilder or live paintbucket

Answer (score 1):

[Segment Definition](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20segment&oq=define%20segment&aqs=chrome..69i57.1638j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Managed to solve my problem using the Shape Builder tool. Select all then use the Shape Builder tool to click into each individual segment to turn them into connected shapes